# Python regex - finding all substrings between two delimiters

Tags: python, regex

I've been dealing with this problem for over a day already and i just can't figure it out..

The problem i have is following:
Given the text:

> Obratite pažnju na sljedece:
>   Pad prometa
>   Rentabilnost imovine
>   Neto maržu
>
> **************************************************************

I need to extract all the text that is between word "sljedece:" ( without qouatiton marks) and the row of asterisks.

I tried to use the following code:

```
import re

text =  """
Obratite pažnju na sljedece:
Pad prometa
Rentabilnost imovine
Neto maržu

**************************************************************
"""
pattern = r"sljecece:(.*?)\*+"
napomene = re.findall(pattern, text)

print(napomene)
```

But it prints out an empty list.

Thx to everyone in advance!

Comment: You have a typo in your current pattern. **`sljecece` vs `sljedece`**

Comment: Why regex? Why don't you `collect = False; for line in text.splitlines(): if line == asterisks: collect = False; if collect: yield line; else if 'sljedece' in line: collect = True;`

Comment: This should do it: `sljedece:(?:.|\n)*\*+`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass `re.DOTALL` to make `.` match newlines:

```
re.findall(pattern, text, re.DOTALL)
```

You also have a typo on your pattern `r"sljecece:(.*?)\*+"` should be `r"sljedece:(.*?)\*+"`.

Comment: just tested it and it works!
thank your very much for help!

Answer (score 0):

To be more efficient, you can limit the impact of the lazy quantifier grabbing entire lines until the asterisk line:

```
re.findall(r'\bsljedece:((?:.*\n)+?)\*+$', text, re.M)
```

Perhaps the `re.search` method is more appropriate in your case.